# I need a formula to have capital letter at the beguining of each cells

Tags: excel

I'm working on excel and i have fulled 300 lines.
I want to have CAPITAL letter at the beguining of each lines;i need a formula.
What can I do because i don't want to waste time by changing lines after lines.

THANK YOU

Comment: I'm afraid you would have to "waste" some more time in "trying".

Answer (score 1):

If your cell's value contains single word you can use

```
=PROPER(A1)
```

if cell can contain few words, use this one:

```
=UPPER(LEFT(A1,1)) & RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)
```